# DevExpress ¿Cómo poner color al titulo de la columna en mi Grid (rejilla)?

Tags: c#, devexpress

He tratado de poner color a todos los títulos de las columnas pero no sé por qué no toma las características que aplico.

Esta es mi Grid (rejilla):

[image: Grilla en la aplicación]

Aquí estoy aplicando las características de apariencia a el Grid (rejilla), todos funcionan menos ese.

[image: Código de configuración de grilla]

Comment: Deberias mencionar que usas el grid de DevExpress que son componente de terceros

Comment: Hola @avargasma. Por favor coloca el texto de tu código en lugar de colocar una imagen. Esto facilita la revisión por parte de los usuarios y la adaptación del código en las respuestas.

Comment: [OffTopic] cada vez que veo componentes DevExpress mi C:\erebro tiene un bufferOverflow x.x

Answer (score 1):

La propiedad UseDefaultLookAndFeel debe ser `false` para poder cambiar el estilo:

```
gridControl.LookAndFeel.UseDefaultLookAndFeel = false;
```

así podrás cambiar el color sin problema:

```
vistaPendiente.Appearance.HeaderPanel.Options.UseBackColor = true;
vistaPendiente.Appearance.HeaderPanel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrias intentar asignar la propiedad [UseDefaultLookAndFeel](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressLookAndFeelUserLookAndFeel_UseDefaultLookAndFeeltopic) en `false`

[How do I set the color of a grid column header panel?](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q200212)

Comment: una duda, a quien voto negativo podria al menso explicar porque ? al menos si votan negativo den una justificacion para poder mejorar